# Share URL on Google+

Tags: google-plus, share

Is it possible to share a URL on Google+ like it´s possible for Facebook or Twitter? Via Hyperlink to a specific URL? Like http://plus.google.com/share?url=http://example.org/ ...

I don´t want to use the +1 Button because I need to style a hyperlink with a selfmade icon.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is a question for webapps.stackexchange.com, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: I´ve found the solution: https://plusone.google.com/u/0/+1/profile/?type=po&ru=http://example.com/

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it is possible.  Click on the post options list (it's the small circle in the upper right part of the post) and you'll see an option that says 'Link to this post'.  Click it!